# Is it really wrong grammatically speaking to say " take advantage from" instead of "take advantage of"

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I found examples of both phrases here https://sentencestack.com/q/take_advantage_from
https://sentencestack.com/q/take_advantage_of

Is taking advantage from people really wrong or just odd? as people would be the source where this advantage is being taken from?

Answer (score 1):

We can **derive advantage from** something. It means to obtain some benefit from it. And so some speakers may use **take** as a synonym for **derive** there. But that is not advisable, as the collocation **take advantage of**, which  means to avail oneself of something but can also mean to exploit someone in an unfair or unjust manner, is so often used that there's more than a little opportunity for misunderstanding if you use **take** as a synonym for **derive** and have that first meaning in mind. It may not be immediately clear to the listener or reader which meaning you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Update: The construction of a sentence where one uses **taking advantage of** instead of **taking advantage from** would be grammatically accurate. See @Kate Bunting's [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/341171/is-it-really-wrong-grammatically-speaking-to-say-take-advantage-from-instead/341182#comment654454_341182).

**But**, the context would lose *semantic value* if we use these two interchangeably, considering they are *at least* used to convey different voices (active and passive) and *at most* different valence. (For example, **taking advantage of** is exclusively negative, where **taking advantage from** has neutral connotation.)

- You take advantage **of** a subject (A person or a situation)
- You take advantage **from** an object (An event, a situation *as object* or an action)

In your provided source, taking the first example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/partner/SentenceStack.com?curid=7804441):

> Thus, businesses would be able to **take advantage from** brand loyalty and further enhance the competitiveness.

Means: *... businesses would benefit from brand loyalty*.

Now same sentence replacing *from* with *of*:

> Thus businesses would be able to **take advantage of** brand loyalty and further enhance the competitiveness.

The meaning is changed. Someone is taking advantage of brand loyalty and that is not what the first sentence is about.

Comment: [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+advantage+of%2C+take+advantage+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows that _Take advantage from_ is hardly ever used. I would call it unidiomatic rather than ungrammatical.

Comment: @KateBunting you are right, a sentence using either of the two phrases is correct grammatically. Updating answer.